# read text table using python

Tags: python, data-structures, text-files

I have a table which looks like this (NB this is a small subsection and there are more than 40 fields here)

[image]

I would like to ask is there a way to read this in Python and store as a list of lists?

```
[[804,01000001,jj,01asdas],[804,0100002,hh,1-NetSassassdasdsds]]
```

Comment: Where has the table come from? That will infer how you can most easily read the data and convert to a list of lists.

Comment: Hi jhole, I got this as a txt file.

Comment: Any delimiters?

Comment: Nope no deliminators

Comment: Your question makes it look like the pipe character | is in fact a delimiter, is this not the case?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the line sequentially, throw the lines that have dashes, split the file, and append it to a list

```
data = []
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if '-' not in line:
            data.append(line.split('|')[1:-1])
```

tested it on the following example

```
----------------------
|id|f1   |f2   |f3   |
----------------------
|12|01001|jj|01|
|12|01001|jj|01|
```

prints the following output

```
[['id', 'f1   ', 'f2   ', 'f3   '],
 ['12', '01001', 'jj', '01'],
 ['12', '01001', 'jj', '01']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw away the first three header lines, strip the outermost `|`s, and then split the line with `|` as a delimiter, and finally strip the white spaces.

Using list comprehension, assuming your table text is stored in `data`:

```
arr = [(f for f in l.strip('|').split('|')) for i, l in enumerate(data.split('\n')) if i > 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments:

```
import pandas as pd

arr = pd.read_csv('path_to_txt_file.txt', sep='|').values.tolist()
```

tested with following textfile:

```
h1|h2|h3
abc|foo|bar
abc2|foo2|bar2
```

output

```
>>> pd.read_csv('random.txt', sep='|').values.tolist()
[['abc', 'foo', 'bar'], ['abc2', 'foo2', 'bar2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I followed - 
1. Read the lines from text file.
2. Split each line with pipe("|") and then extract only those elements which have any alphanumeric characters.
3. Finally, remove the empty list from the list of list (to leave out 1st and 3rd line).

Here is the code -

```
lines = open("test.txt","r").readlines()
l = []
for line in lines :
    temp = line.split("|")
    l = l + [[x.strip() for x in temp if re.match('^[\w-]+$', x.strip()) is not None]]
finalList = [x for x in l if x != []]
```

finalList should give you the desired answer.